# How to find first byte of a serial stream with python?

Tags: python, python-3.3, pyserial

I am trying to read a Datastream from RS232 with python 3.3.2 and pyserial. I start the stream with:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=19200, timeout=3, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO)
ser.write(bytes([0x05, 0x69, 0x02, 0x0A, 0x86]))
```

After this i get every second a 107 byte long dataset. First byte should be 107 (number of bytes) and second one should be 105 (Code).

What is the best way to seperate one 107 byte long dataset starting with 107 and 105? If I use `print(ser.read(107))` a few times I get:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\xbf\x99\x10\xe0}\x86\xaaV\xd4\xeeg\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x87}i\xdf\n\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc1\xc3k\x00\x00\x00\xc0t\xb4\xbd\xf0\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x80\xc7\x10\xc0\xcd\xe6G\x0b\x99\xd4\xcb.'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc5\xeck\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xf4\xb3\xbd\xf0\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0V\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\xc8\x10@\xcd\xe67\x8b\x99\xd4\x0b/\x00\x00@\x00\xf6\xb7\xbf\xfd\xed\xaf:\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xf3J\xaf\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\xbf\x99\x18\xe0}\x86\xaaV\xd4\xeeg\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

The `k` (ascii for 107) is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Your sample datastream doesn't have the sequence `b'ki'` in it, which corresponds to `chr(107)+chr(105)`, in it. What have you tried?

Comment: oh sorry thats right i have to figure out why.. but if we suppose in the stream is ki.. do you have an idea??

Comment: When if the data you've read was in a list called `data`, you could use `b''.join(data).find(bytes((107, 105)))` to find the offset of the pattern if it exists (otherwise it returns `-1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful to flush your input before you put the request. I.e.,

```
ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
```

to read out all bytes which are waiting. Then, hoping that no further bytes are being sent, you can send your command:

```
ser.write(bytes([0x05, 0x69, 0x02, 0x0A, 0x86]))
```

This is supposed to make sure that all bytes which are coming next are an answer to this command.

Then read data until you get your 107:

```
found = False
buffer = '' # what is left from the previous run...
while not found:
    rd = ser.read(50)
    buffer += rd
    sp = buffer.split(chr(107), 1)
    if len(sp) == 2:
        pkt = chr(107) + sp[1] # candidate for a valid packet
        if pkt[1] == chr(105): # 
            while len(pkt) < 107: # TODO add a timeout condition here...
                rd = ser.read(107 - len(pkt))
                pkt += rd
            found = True
        else:
            buffer = pkt[1:] # process this further...
    else: # no 107 found; empty the buffer.
        buffer = ''
# Now we have a pkt of 107 bytes and can do whatever we want with it.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it seems like there are no bytes with 107 followed by 105. I did a lot of testing, played with the timeouts and the rate of packets per minute. the

Comment: without success. Most of the time there is a `)` or 41 after the `k` 107. Do you have any idea why this could happen? Most accurate thing was `b'k}i...'`

Comment: @user158365 There I cannot help you. Either your device is malfunctionning, or something else is wrong. If you have access to the source device's firmware, I would change the protocol to have something like packet boundaries and maybe even a checksum.

Comment: I have now the right protocol and your way works great. Thanks a lot!!